# How to invert the selection in vim?

Tags: vim

After selecting a range of lines with the `V` command, I would like to delete every line of the file that is NOT selected, so is a way to invert the selection -- select every line that is not selected?

Like how

```
:g!/FOO/d
```

deletes every line which does **NOT** contain *FOO*.

If I had a range in mind and wanted to use its inverse:

```
'a,'b
```

I would need to use the two ranges:

```
1,'a-1
```

and

```
'b+1,$
```

I suspect that this cannot be done in one step -- but it would be nice!

Comment: so you want a "crop"-style operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create the following mapping (for example bound to the `<F4>` key)

```
map <F4> :<C-U>1,'<-1:delete<CR>:'>+1,$:delete<CR>
```

then, after selecting a range in visual mode, just press `<F4>` to trigger the associated command. The command can be easily explained in parts:

- "`:`" Enter command line mode.
- "`<C-U>`" Remove all characters between the cursor position and the beginning of the line.
- "`1,'<-1`" Specifiy the range from the first line of the file to the line before the start of current selection.
- "`:delete<CR>`"   Delete (the previously specified range of lines).
- "`:'>+1,$:delete<CR>`" Delete the lines in the range "`'>+1,$`", i.e. from the line after the end of the selection to the end of the file.

Comment: just to explain it:  1,'< - 1  is the range from line 1 upto the start of the selection. '> + 1,$ is the range from 1 line after the selection upto the end...

Comment: Is there some way to do that with only one "delete" command?

Comment: @Kevin Panko: you'd need to combine the ranges into a single expression.  i've looked at the docs and i don't think the range syntax supports such a thing.  http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-ranges ,,, http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges

Answer (score 16):

1. select your text
2. `"*yggdG"*p`   which means ...

   ```
   "*y    " yank it to the selection register
   ggdG   " delete everything
   "*p    " and paste the selection again
   ```

Comment: ygg"_dGP is the same but shorter.

Comment: in the end you get the same text, true :)

Comment: I would like just refer to akira and Kevin Panko answers (I cannot add comments). " [o]pposite [d]elete in (v)isual mode vmap od ygg"_dGP

Comment: Plugins like https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack make this approach easier. You don't have to worry as much about your yank register getting clobbered by the delete.

Comment: how can this be added as keyboard mapping in `.vimrc` ? I've tried a few attempts but haven't gotten it yet. My attempts were `map <F4> n"*yggdG"*p
` and `nmap <F4> "*yggdG"*p`

Comment: ahh.. found it ! This worked for me to map it to `F4`. Just add this to your .vimrc, `map <F4> "*yggdG"*p`

Answer (score 11):

Just for posterity:

```
:v/\%V/d
```

That does an inverse global on lines that are not part of the selection. Note that :v is a line-based construct, so any line that contains any of the selection, be it line, stream, or block selection will be spared deletion.

Answer (score 1):

since 'inverting' means basically to create 'multiselections' (the area before and after the original selection) i searched the vimscripts again http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953. try this.

```
 There are a number of operations to very
 easily manipulate selections such as modifying 
 the regions (add/delete/inverte/clear), hiding, 
 refreshing, saving and restoring etc."
```