# Use vim in pipeline to dump current line on exit to stdout?

Tags: bash, vim, zsh, pipe

Is it possible for me to do something like this:

```
$ ls | vim | xargs ...
```

and have vim pass to stdout any lines that were visually selected on exit?

If it'd be easier to just dump the "current line" then that'd work too.

I'm of course open to passing some command line args to vim, or a custom vimrc to make it work.

NOTE: I want to use this to allow me to select any piece of text, whether or not it's a full line or parts of a single line, interactively at the command line using VIM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works with vim pretty easily, so now I can do things like this

```
$ ls | choose.sh | xargs ....
```

This starts up vim, allows me to visually select the text I want, and passes the selected text to stdout when I press `F4`. Note that I could also just edit the buffer and modify it to only contain the text I want to select, save and exit, and the contents of the buffer would be passed to stdout. So all the power of vim to "choose" something at the command line interactively!

I can do this using vim by adding the following to my `.vimrc` (snagged [from here](https://superuser.com/a/72720/38941))

```
map <F4> "*yggdG"*pZZ
```

and saving the following to a script (snagged [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686830/26510))

### choose.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# create temporary file
TMPFILE=`mktemp /tmp/vipe.bashXXXXXXXX`
cat > ${TMPFILE}
vim ${TMPFILE} < /dev/tty > /dev/tty
cat ${TMPFILE}
rm ${TMPFILE}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `choose.sh` basically reimplements the `vipe` (*vi pipe*) command from *moreutils*:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>     command1 | vipe | command2
>
> DESCRIPTION
>     vipe allows you to run your editor in the middle of a unix pipeline and
>     edit the data that is being piped between programs. Your editor will
>     have the full data being piped from command1 loaded into it, and when
>     you close it, that data will be piped into command2.
> ```

Comment: For sure! Good point. The only real difference I see is that vipe forces you to edit the content, deleting everything but what you want. My approach above allows me to just visually select the text I want, hit F4, and that's what's sent to output - so less keyboard work, in my opinion. I actually came across that script when looking for vipe info.